# Can we Run WPF application On Windows 10 Tab.Using VS2013

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-desktop

I'm planing to make offline Module using WPF visual studio 2013 and mysql , my main concern is ,Will it work On windows 10 tablet ?

I have seen Windows 10 tab-view in my desktop but is it same with  windows 10 tablet ?
I'm Not looking for Mobile only for tab?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to upgrade to Visual Studio 2015 if you want to develop a Universal Windows App (Windows 10).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn975273.aspx

PD I couldn't write it in a comment due to I'm newbie